# Is there a way to use the Gatsby page query or static query with the React Context API?

Tags: reactjs, gatsby, contentful, react-context

I need to create a cart for an e-commerce website so all of the pages need to have access to the cart information, hence the need for the Context API. The problem is that Gatsby will only fetch information for rendered pages or components, I can't seem to find any way to query my Contentful data from the Context component which is not rendered. I have tried so many things and searched every corner of the internet.

Is there a way to do this? Or is there a way to create the cart without the Context API? Bearing in mind I have no back-end experience so am not able to create a server to deal with that.

P.S. I was eventually successful when using a simple fetch method within the Context API, but when I build the project on Contentful it causes a problem with environment variables, so the only solution to that was to expose the API key for the world to see  Which is a terrible, terrible solution.

Comment: Where is your cart data persisted? You aren't allowed to use Contentful as the storage solution for that—they will boot you off the platform for doing so.

Comment: What do you mean? I just need to pull a list of products from Contentful one time to be stored in an object that can then be updated from anywhere in the site.

Comment: So I want to pull the product list directly in to the useContext module as soon as it is loaded

Comment: Ah, I understand what you're after now. Dropped an answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want a [Static Query](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/static-vs-normal-queries/), which will allow you to query all of your product data, making it available client-side. Instead of using React Context for this, I'd recommend a custom React Hook, which will allow you to import the data where you need it and let Webpack handle chunking and loading it.

Here's an example with some fake schema:

```
import { useStaticQuery, graphql } from "gatsby"

const useProductData = (id) => {
  const { data: { products } } = useStaticQuery(graphql`
    {
      data: allContentfulProduct {
        products: nodes {
          id
          name
          price
        }
      }
    }
  `)

  // Wee little usage nicety here to only return the relevant product
  // if an id is passed into the hook arguments.
  return id ? products.find(product => product.id === id) : products
}

const CartProduct = ({ productId }) => {
  const product = useProductData(productId)
  return (
    <div>
      {name} ${price.toFixed(2)}
    </div>
  )
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for responding  but I don't understand how this would work. I'm going to play around with it and see if I get it. I always thought a static query would be ideal if only I get it to work. Maybe this would go in the navbar so that it is always rendered and therefore retains data across the site...  Thanks again for your response

Comment: Save the hook as a separate file (e.g. src/hooks/useProductData.js) and import it into any component you want to use the data in. No need to worry about duplicating data or loading it multiple times because Webpack will automatically take care of that for you, ensuring there’s only one of it and loading the chunk only on pages that need it.

Comment: This was perfect, thank you!!! I still ended up using the Context API because I couldn't figure out a way to store the cart state using custom hooks, but it works great. I'm just calling the custom hook with useEffect at the start of the context provider to give me a product list and then can even condense my code a lot because of the feature you added where I can pass in an id to just get a single product.

Beautiful, thank you so much.

Comment: While I was running around learning about custom hooks I found another answer that you had provided. It seems you are a very important part of the React community. Thank you for all the help you have provided to the community ❤

Comment: @erasebegin Glad you got it working, and thank you for the kind words!